# How to password protect Advanced Custom Fields in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, field, password-protection

I'm trying to password protect some custom fields generated by the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

This is the code that I need to hide:

```
<h2>
   <?php the_field('page_title'); ?>
</h2>

<div class="fusion-one-half one_half fusion-column">
  <h2>
    <?php the_field('subtitle_1'); ?>
  </h2>
    <?php the_field('list_1'); ?>
</div>

<div class="fusion-one-third one_third fusion-column last">
  <h2>
    <?php the_field('subtitle_2'); ?>
  </h2>
    <?php the_field('list_2'); ?>
</div>
```

I have seen this link https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Password_Protection but don't know how to use it with my code.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I presume that you already have your answer but if you don't then try the following:

```
 if ( post_password_required() ) {

      echo get_the_password_form();

 } else {  

 'Password Protected Custom Content'

     }
```

You can find a more detailed response here http://htotheml.com/password-protect-custom-templates-in-wordpress/